# Replacing a regex match with the length of matched text

Tags: python, regex

How to replace patterns like `<html>` and `</mainbody>` by `<4>` and `</8>`. Here 4 and 8 are the number of alphabets inside <>.
Input is to be taken from file.

```
import re
def main():
        fh=open("input.txt")
        pattern=re.compile("</?[a-zA-Z]+>") #regular expression to find patterns <html>, </html> 
        for line in fh:
                print(re.sub(pattern,"***",line.strip()))



if __name__=="__main__":main()
```

Comment: what you mean by *like <html> and </mainbody> by <4> and </8>* ??? can you explain more clear your request? i can interpret a lot of meaning from your sentence ! and also whats the problem with your code ?

Comment: i have to replace tags such as <html> ,</html>, <funbody> by tags like <4>, </4> ,<7>.

Comment: what you mean by *like* ? whats the logic behind this task ? whay 4 and 7 are you mean just number or if you mean just number is it random ?

Comment: they are the number of alphabets inside <> or</>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom method to return the length of the match:

```
def get_length(obj):
    s = obj.groups()[0]
    return '</{}>'.format(len(s[1:])) if s.startswith('/') else '<{}>'.format(len(s))

>>> re.sub("<(/?[a-zA-Z]+)>", get_length, '<html>')
'<4>'
>>> re.sub("<(/?[a-zA-Z]+)>", get_length, '</html>')
'</4>'
```

I hope you realize your regular expression is very basic, and it won't deal with tags that have attributes correctly.